# Others called his house asking for "Dr. Butcher"

Tags: phrase-meaning

Why use "asking for" - why not simply "Others called his house   "Dr. Butcher""? Using *asking for* sounds as if the house is inviting people to name it. I am not sure.

> White became a target for protestors because of his head transplantation experiments. One interrupted a banquet in his honor by offering him a bloody replica of a human head. **Others called his house asking for "Dr. Butcher"**. When White testified in a civil hearing about Dr. Sam Sheppard's murder case, lawyer Terry Gilbert compared Dr. White to Dr. Frankenstein.[9] The People for the Ethical Treatment of Animals described White's experiments as "epitomizing the crude, cruel vivisection industry".[10]

> Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head_transplant)

Comment: Here, calling his house means phoning his residence.  Imagine these protestors starting phone calls with something like "Hello, can I speak to Dr. Butcher, please?"  It has nothing to do with giving the house a nickname.

Comment: @GaryBotnovcan  That should probably be an answer.  I was just about to write basically the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this sentence the house is not doing the asking. We have:

> People[subject] called[verb] hishouse[object] askingfor[participle] DrButcher[object].

Stripping the sentence down, we have people [subject] asking for [verb] Dr. Butcher [object]. The sentence is made more complex by describing *how* they asked: they called his house, meaning they *dialed* the telephone that was in his house. It does not mean the house requested to be *named* something; that is a different definition of "call."

The meaning of the sentence is that people were upset at him, and wanted to annoy him. So they telephoned his home phone and asked if "Dr. Butcher" was available to talk, even though that is not his name.